# How to use Visual Studio Community with Fortran?

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, lapack

My thesis professor asked my to install and run some code so I can get thermodynamic properties. I need to run [thermopack](https://github.com/SINTEF/thermopack/) to get the quantum properties of hydrogen.

I followed the instructions in the link, installed Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022, with Python development, C++ development, and data science analysis F#. Also installed Intel OneAPI base and the toolkit for Fortran. I followed https://icl.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/ tutorial for libraries installation, but so far I can only open the document and whenever I try to compile I get two errors "The CompatibiltyToolPackage did not load correctly" and "Visual Studio cannot debug because a debug target has not been specified". Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. I strongly suggest to first learn how to call the compiler from the command prompt (e.g. Powershell on Windows or bash on Linux) and only thereafter try employing more advanced toolset that is normally only necessary for larger projects that you continuously develop. To get some code compiled and running it is overkill to employ so many tools.

Comment: The "cannot debug" error is usually because you are trying to debug a library (static or DLL) project where no executable has been specified in the Debugging > Command property. If you have a VS solution with two projects, one executable and one library, make sure that the executable project is the Startup project (right click on that project and select Set as Startup Project.

For the "did not load" error, try uninstalling and reinstalling the Intel Fortran compiler (HPC toolkit or independent install).